# How to set default settings for switch turned on enabled with VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I have a script coded in VueJS. It currently has two switch buttons that are called R-18 & R18G and they both currently unchecked on default. The function of these switches do is it will filter content that is displayed on the site if you toggle the switch to checked. What I want to do is have both switches to be set checked on default. How can I fix this?

```
<template>
  <div class="setting">
    <van-cell center title="cache" :label="size.local | bytes">
      <template #right-icon>
        <van-button type="primary" size="small" @click="clearCache('local')">clean up</van-button>
      </template>
    </van-cell>
    <van-cell center title="runtime cleanup" :label="size.session | bytes">
      <template #right-icon>
        <van-button type="info" size="small" @click="clearCache('session')">clean up</van-button>
      </template>
    </van-cell>
    <van-cell center title="R-18" label="NSFW">
      <template #right-icon>
        <van-switch :value="currentSETTING.r18" @input="onR18Change($event, 1)" size="24" />
      </template>
    </van-cell>
    <van-cell center title="R-18G" label="Extreme NSFW">
      <template #right-icon>
        <van-switch :value="currentSETTING.r18g" @input="onR18Change($event, 2)" size="24" />
      </template>
    </van-cell>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Cell, Switch, Button, Dialog } from "vant";
import { mapState, mapActions } from "vuex";
import { LocalStorage, SessionStorage } from "@/utils/storage";
export default {
  name: "Setting",
  data() {
    return {
      currentSETTING: {
        r18: false,
        r18g: false
      },
      size: {
        local: 0,
        session: 0
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["SETTING"])
  },
  watch: {
    $route() {
      this.calcCacheSize();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onR18Change(checked, type) {
      let name;
      if (type === 1) name = "R-18";
      if (type === 2) name = "R-18G";
      if (checked) {
        Dialog.confirm({
          message: `Are you sure you want to enable the display of R-18`,
          confirmButtonColor: "black",
          cancelButtonColor: "#1989fa",
          closeOnPopstate: true
        })
          .then(() => {
            if (type === 1) this.currentSETTING.r18 = checked;
            if (type === 2) {
              this.currentSETTING.r18g = checked;
              setTimeout(() => {
                Dialog.alert({
                  message: `Please note that turning on R-18G switch may have irreversible effects `
                });
              }, 200);
            }
          })
          .catch(() => {
            console.log("cancel");
          });
      } else {
        if (type === 1) this.currentSETTING.r18 = checked;
        if (type === 2) this.currentSETTING.r18g = checked;
      }
    },
    calcCacheSize() {
      this.size.local = LocalStorage.size;
      this.size.session = SessionStorage.size;
    },
    clearCache(type) {
      let showName;
      switch (type) {
        case "local":
          showName = "cache";
          break;
        case "session":
          showName = "runtime cache";
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      Dialog.confirm({
        message: `Are you sure you want to clean up?`,
        confirmButtonColor: "black",
        cancelButtonColor: "#1989fa",
        closeOnPopstate: true
      }).then(() => {
        if (type === "local") LocalStorage.clear();
        if (type === "session") SessionStorage.clear();
        this.calcCacheSize();
        this.$toast.success("cleaned up");
      });
    },
    ...mapActions(["saveSETTING"])
  },
  filters: {
    bytes(bytes) {
      bytes = Number(bytes);
      if (bytes === 0) return "0 B";
      const k = 1024;
      const dm = 0;
      const sizes = ["B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB"];
      const i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
      return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + " " + sizes[i];
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.currentSETTING = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.SETTING));
    this.calcCacheSize();
  },
  updated() {
    this.saveSETTING(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.currentSETTING)));
  },
  components: {
    [Cell.name]: Cell,
    [Button.name]: Button,
    [Switch.name]: Switch
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="stylus" scoped>
.setting {
}
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the currentSETTING.r18 and currentSETTING.r18g values to true in your data object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of Excalibaard is correct.
When you declare your data in the vue component, whatever value you pass to them, that will be the inital state for them.
In your case if you data values to `true` will work for you.

Be careful, that when we request and populate our component's data, we declare them as null. That will prevent any unwanted initial app states, and ensure that you will only have access on them after request response.